# Spring Security and Shiro -> How to pass a token with authenticated user to Shiro?

Tags: spring, security, authentication, shiro

I've two web applications: the first web application is using Spring MVC and Security and it makes user's authentication at database. And works fine, thanks.

The second web-app is using Shiro for user's login to grant the authorities and etc.

Question: How can I make login at the first app and pass the token csrf, or another one, from the Spring Security to the shiro and use it for your necessities?

If you could send me a tutorials or examples of this, I'd appreciate.

Thanks.